# bumblebee: X did not start properly

Tags: xorg, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, gpu, gpu-driver

Bumblebee doesn't work, without giving me any clear error message other than "X did not start properly".

Here is the result of `optirun -vvv glxgears` :

```
[19243.370955] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[19243.400070] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[19243.400238] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[19243.400249] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[19243.400257] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[19243.400268] [DEBUG] X display: :0
[19243.400272] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current
[19243.400277] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[19243.400285] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[19243.400292] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[19243.400315] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[19243.400323] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
[19243.400465] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge primus
[19243.405523] [INFO]Response: No - error: [XORG] (EE) 

[19243.405542] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) 

[19243.405546] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[19243.405571] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[19243.405576] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

`service bumblebeed status` :

```
oct. 21 00:57:36 magix-X550LD bumblebeed[4677]: No protocol specified
oct. 21 00:57:36 magix-X550LD bumblebeed[4677]: [19243.405461] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
oct. 21 00:57:36 magix-X550LD bumblebeed[4677]: [19243.405483] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
oct. 21 00:57:36 magix-X550LD bumblebeed[4677]: [19243.405487] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
oct. 21 00:57:36 magix-X550LD bumblebeed[4677]: [19243.405491] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
oct. 21 00:57:36 magix-X550LD bumblebeed[4677]: [19243.405495] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
oct. 21 00:57:36 magix-X550LD bumblebeed[4677]: [19243.405499] [ERROR]X did not start properly
```

I will post my bumblebee.conf if needed, the only thing I changed is the KernelDriver name of the `driver-nvidia` section to nvidia-340, otherwise it would complain about the driver.

I tried changing the display number from :8 to :0, with no effect.

Any clue about what could be wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

my optimus system (dell m3800 , intel 4600 + nvidia quadro k1100m) doesn't use bumblebee or primus , i don't have either package installed, if you do i would recommend you remove them with.

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee primus
```

I am using nvidia drivers from the ubuntu graphics drivers ppa and nvidia-prime. I have no xorg.conf in /etc/X11/.

To add the ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

for more info about the ppa and which version to use go here

https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa